# Does using console command mark you as cheater?

Tags: pc, the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, achievements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Do console commands affect Steam achievements?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37694/do-console-commands-affect-steam-achievements)

If I use console commands in Skyrim do I risk to be marked as "cheater" by the game and preclude me some possibilities or achievements?