# What are known side effects of using the console in Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I got so fed up with my low carry rate that I modified it via the console.  Now the next zone I enter, I get a block-like drawing error on the loading screen.  Then I notice a few more little quirks that I've never seen shortly thereafter.

Are there known side effects to using the console?

Comment: Jealous people playing on the 360 and PS3 that can't use the console.

Comment: Related: [Does using console command mark you as cheater?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35155/does-using-console-command-mark-you-as-cheater)

Comment: The use of console commands can affect virtually anything in the game — that's what it's for.  You're better off Googling for a list of console commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think player related console command would cause any graphical issues, unless you entered a wrong command by mistake, or just randomly encountered another bug right after using your console cheat.